# Is there a way to implement a function with an optional argument of a generic type in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, generics

I am trying to learn some Scala by "rewriting" some of my PySpark code. I have a list of data-sources that all have a list of transforms that needs to be applied. Some of these are common, some are not, so I set up a trait with some common functions like this:

```
trait Common[S, R] {

  def call(spark: SparkSession)(sourceDS: Dataset[S]): Dataset[R]

  def commonTr1(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    df.withColumn("cmn1", lit(1))
  }

}
```

and example implementation:

```
object Source1 extends Common[SourceType, ResultType] {

  override def call(spark: SparkSession)(sourceDS: Dataset[SourceType]): Dataset[ResultType] = {
    import spark.implicits._

    sourceDS.toDF().transform(commonTr1).as[ResultType]
  }
}
```

but then I have some functions that require an additional dataset, e.g.:

```
  def call(spark: SparkSession, extraDS: Dataset[ExtraType])(sourceDS: Dataset[SourceType]): Dataset[ResultType] = {
    import spark.implicits._

    sourceDS.toDF().transform(commonTr1).join(extraDS.toDF(), "id", "left").as[ResultType]
  }
```

I tried adding extraDS with default as None in the trait, and setting the generic to _ or Any or similar, or by adding a overloaded function, but have not found a way to make this work,

e.g.: (Does not work)

```
trait Common[S, R, T] {

  def call(spark: SparkSession, extraDS: Option[Dataset[T]] = None)(sourceDS: Dataset[S]): Dataset[R]

  def commonTr1(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    df.withColumn("cmn1", lit(1))
  }

}

object Source1 extends Common[SourceType, ResultType, _] {

  override def call(spark: SparkSession, extraDS: Option[Dataset[_]] = None)(sourceDS: Dataset[SourceType]): Dataset[ResultType] = {
    import spark.implicits._

    sourceDS.toDF().transform(commonTr1).as[ResultType]
  }
}
```

Now, first: I am pretty sure I am using the underscore keyword wrong here, second: even if it worked, I feel like it is a bad solution (as the 'extraDS' is either required or not used at all, and never optional).

Does anyone have a suggestion on either how to make this work, or a suggestion for an alternative solution?

Comment: Could you make `T` a type parameter of `call`? The two underscores in `Source1`'s definition are different.

Comment: Making `T` a type parameter of `call` would "work", but it would remove some of the benefits of using a dataset instead of a dataframe (as the implementations of `call` would also have to use `T` instead of e.g.  `ExtraType`)